# Uniform continuity of heat equation with $L^1$ data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, heat-equation

I came across the following remark in my reading.

> **Remark.** If the initial data is in $L^{1}$, then heat equation solutions approach $0$ within the sup-norm. That is, if $K(x,t)$ is the heat kernel and $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then
> $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} K(x - y, t)f(y)dy = 0,$$
> uniformly.

I can picture this working if $f$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. **Does $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ imply this somehow, and I'm not seeing this?** I'm relatively new to $L^{p}$-spaces.

---

If so, then for $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some radius $r_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that $|f(y)| < \epsilon/2$.

Then we can bound the heat kernel, and use the fact that, $\int K(x-y, t)dy = 1$ to conclude, more or less.

Comment: As stated that doesn't make sense, either you want the time to go to infinity or the other side should be $f(x)$.

Comment: Anyway, say $u(x,t,f)$ solves the heat equation with initial data $f$. Then the so called semigroup property tells you that this is just $u(x,t-\epsilon,u(x,\epsilon,f))$. The new initial condition when you restart st time $\epsilon$ is smooth and $L^1$ so your idea now works.

Comment: Yes, $t \to \infty$, edited. Could you expand on the semigroup property that makes my idea work? Link or book to it (I have Evan's if he discusses this somewhere) would be great otherwise.

Comment: Evans definitely discusses the smoothing property of the heat equation, which is the nontrivial thing you need. The semigroup property itself is more or less trivial, at least from the point of view of PDE.

Comment: I should say, the nontrivial thing you need to go from this angle. There is a more direct alternative as the answer shows.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I have a proof in my mind using approach in OP. I'll read up on your recommendations to finish it off. Answer is an elegant substitute nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite straightforward from the definition. In $n$ dimensions, the heat kernel is given by
$$ K(x-y,t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{-|x-y|^2/4t}. $$
As $e^{-x} \leq 1$ for $x \geq 0$ this implies that $|K(x-y,t)| \leq  {(4\pi t)^{-n/2}}$ and therefore
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} K(x - y, t)f(y)dy \right| \leq  {(4\pi t)^{-n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)|dy,$$
which converges to $0$ as $t \to \infty$ uniformly in $x$, as soon as $f$ is in $L^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: I see. I guess I was going about the long way. Since $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\int |f(y)|dy < \infty$, and the result follows as $t \to \infty$. Thanks.